# What things can be done to make a Bash script containing sudo commands, running with the timer schedule ‘crontab’ work?

Tags: shell-script, centos, cron

I try to run a script that I named `script1.sh`:

```
out="/home/me/scripts/out.txt"
sudo ntpdate 99.99.99.99 >> $out
```

on a timer with the crontab in a **Centos 7** operation system. The aim of this is to automatically synchronize the Centos 7 time with a time server.

Using the commands

```
crontab –e             # (1)
sudo crontab –e        # (2)
sudo vi /etc/crontab   # (3),
```

I pasted a string of a schedule definition in every configuration file (1), (2), and (3). The string is

```
* */1 * * *   me   /home/me/scripts/script1.sh
```

Then I apply the `sudo systemctl reload crond.service` command to implement the new configurations.

According to the above schedule, the `script1.sh` must execute every one hour. However, the problem is the ntpdate requires `sudo` permission and hence the `script1.sh` does the same thing. Googling this problem, I found that the `sudo` password requirement could be taken off with editing the `sudoer` configuration file using the `sudo visudo` command to start editing. Then I added to the bottom of its some permissions for no password accessing:

```
me   ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:   /home/me/scripts/*
me   ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:   /usr/sbin/ntpdate
```

At first it was working when it was defined in all three (1), (2), and (3). Then since I commented the schedule definition in (2) and (3), and reloaded the crontab – it would stop working and start asking  the sudo password. Then I returned it back as was, but no effect was watched.

### Question

Could you prompt what to do? What thing can be done to get it working?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to trigger a root-requiring operation through your user's crontab, you should use the system crontab, and then you simply don't *need* `sudo`, because things are *already* running as root.

But in this concrete case, it really seems like you're doing the wrong thing, technically. `ntpdate` shouldn't be used like that; that's just a guarantee for sudden time jumps and continuously drifting clocks.

So, scrap that script and install `chrony`, and appropriately [configure](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chrony#Configuration) `/etc/chrony.conf`, and enable it: `sudo systemctl enable --now chronyd`. Chrony is exactly the kind of daemon you want to keep your clock synchronous with NTP servers with minimal errors.